# Integral involving Square roots of polynomials: $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^a}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I was working on a problem and reduced it to evaluating

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+x^a}\,dx~~a>0$$

your suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with hypergeometric functions? You will most likely need them here.

Comment: The cases $a=3,4$ can of course be expressed as elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^a}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}x^{ka}\mathrm dx,$$
where
$$\binom{1/2}{k}=\frac{(1/2)(1/2-1)\dots(1/2-k+1)}{k!}.$$
We get
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}\frac1{1+ka}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty.$$
Let us rewrite $(1/2)(1/2-1)\cdots(1/2-k+1)=(-1)^k(-\frac12)_k$ where the rising Pochhammer symbol $(x)_n=(x)(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$ is used. We can also rewrite $1+ka=a(\frac1a+k)$ as $$1+ka=a\frac{(\frac1a)_{k+1}}{(\frac1a)_k}=\frac{(1+\frac1a)_k}{(\frac1a)_k}.$$
Therefore the integral rewrites
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-\frac12)_k(\frac1a)_k}{(1+\frac1a)_k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}={}_2F_1\left(-\frac12,\frac1a;\,1+\frac1a\,\middle|\,-1\right)$$
by definition of the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a>0$ we have:
$$ \color{red}{I(a)}=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+x^a}\,dx = \phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{a};1+\frac{1}{a};-1\right) \tag{1}$$
by just expanding $\sqrt{1+z}$ as a Taylor series. Approximations for the RHS can be computed from:
$$ I(a) = \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{1} z^{\frac{1}{a}-1}\sqrt{1+z}\,dz\color{red}{\approx}\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{1}z^{\frac{1}{a}-1}\left(1+(\sqrt{2}-1)z\right)\,dz =  \color{red}{\frac{a+\sqrt{2}}{a+1}}.\tag{2}$$
A better approximation can be computed from 
$$\forall z\in[0,1],\qquad \sqrt{1+z}\approx 1+(2\sqrt{6}-3-\sqrt{2})\,z+(2+2 \sqrt{2}-2 \sqrt{6})\,z^2 \tag{3}$$
that gives:

> $$ I(a)\approx \frac{2a^2+(2\sqrt{6}-1)a+\sqrt{2}}{(a+1)(2a+1)}.\tag{4} $$